# Как можно улучшить данное в примере условие?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Есть такое условие в коде:

```
if 'pdf_path' in item['item'] and item['item']['pdf_path'] is not None and "storage/om" in item['item']['pdf_path']:
```

По мне, выглядит ужасно, можете, плз, подсказать, как можно было бы улучшить данное условие (и возможно ли это?)

Comment: А можно чуть больше кода? Как item выглядит?

Comment: @Сергей на самом деле, это почти весь код. Это обработка ответа json, где может не прийти ничего, none в ключе или искомая строка.

Answer (score 0):

Если item['item']['pdf_path'] содержит в себе только одно значение, то тогда, если item['item']['pdf_path'] хранит в себе "storage/om", проверка на None выполняется неявно.
В этом случае условие преобразуется в:

```
if 'pdf_path' in item['item'] and "storage/om" in item['item']['pdf_path']:
```

Comment: Нет, поскольку если item['item']['pdf_path'] окажется None проверка `"storage/om" in item['item']['pdf_path']:` приведет к ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать временную переменную и словарный метод get. Тогда не понадобится дополнительное `and`

```py
temp = item['item'].get('pdf_path')
if not temp:
    temp = ()
if "storage/om" in temp:
```

PS: не очень люблю длинные условия, лучше их тем или иным образом делать разделенными или обходиться любыми другими способами. Ну это, как я считаю дело вкуса. Если требуется все же одно условие, то вот мой намудренный вариант:

```
if "storage/om" in (temp if (temp := item['item'].get('pdf_path')) else ()):
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно через `try/except` сделать, убрав все промежуточные проверки:

```py
try:
    if "storage/om" in item['item']['pdf_path']:
        print('Есть!')
except:
    pass
```

В случае, когда путь до нужного элемента довольно длинный, это может быть неплохим вариантом.